# elegant jquery search bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i have a list of posts on a page with a search bar at the top of the page. is there a way to get the contents of the search bar when the user hits enter?

i don't want to submit a form but i want to get the contents of the search bar without leaving the page. i think i'd be able to get the contents of the field using `$("#txt_name").attr('value');` but is there a way I can just get the value when the user hits enter inside the search box?

then depending on what they search i'd be able to check the `<div>` id's and see if they match. if they don't match then fade them out...

Comment: Ever find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should help:

http://jsfiddle.net/Batfan/vWMXm/

This listens for the [enter] key to be pressed on the input field and hides/shows elements based on if they contain text matching the query. All results are displayed on a blank search. **See below**:

```
$(document).on("keypress","#searchbox",function(e){
    var userVal = $(this).val();
    if(e.which == 13) {
      $( "li" ).each(function() {
          if($(this).text().match(new RegExp(userVal, "i"))) {
              $(this).show();
          } else if(userVal == "") {
               $(this).show();   
          } else {
               $(this).hide();   
          }
       });
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach event handler function to your input element

```
var $search = $("#txt_name").on('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert($search.val());
  }
})
```

Comment: you may also want to stop event propagation after you handle the Enter key. to do that add e.stopPropagation(); after alert statement.

Comment: or you can just return 'false' value from handler function